# CSS on iPhone 6 giving some problems

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

Hi guys I've been trying to work on iPhone 6 CSS (responsive),but i have no luck the iPhone 5 and 6 CSS is working fine in chrome iPhone emulator and http://mobiletest.me/ ,but the same style is not working on the actual device.

Anyone have idea?
My media queries are,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {}
```

and

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {}
```

also tried

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 649px) {}
```

Help.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` between your `<head></head>` For more info visit https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: I was having <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0"> I don't see why it is disturbing\

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```